# How do I prove this inequality using the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function (that's not necessarily continuous, bounded, or any other property) and let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $h'(x)=10+7\sin(f(x))$. Prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a<b$, then $h(b)-h(a) \geq 3(b-a)$.

So right off the bat, I think the inequality tips off that I'll be using the MVT. Here's what I worked through so far:

$$h(b)-h(a) \geq 3(b-a)$$
$$h'(x)=\frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a} \geq 3$$

So, by MVT we know $h'(x)=10+7\sin(f(x)) \geq 3$

Now I'm not sure what to do next, or if I'm even on the right track. Can someone help out here?

Comment: $-1\le \sin y \le 1$ for any real $y$.

Comment: By the way, note that since $h$ is differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$, it must be the case that $f$ is also continuous on all of $\Bbb R$. Otherwise $h$ would be undefined for some $x$ where $f(x)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By MVT you know that there exists some $x \in [a,b]$ such that:

$$h'(x) = 10 + 7\sin(f(x)) = \frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a}$$

Then note that $\sin$ can only take values in $[1,-1]$. So the maximum and minimum possible values of $h'(x)$ are $10+7\cdot 1 = 17$ and $10 + 7 \cdot (-1) = 3$. By the equality above, we thus have:

$$3 \leq \frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a} \leq 17$$

Where we just want the first bit. Then we just rearrange things:

\begin{align}
3 &\leq \frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-a}
\\
3({b-a}) &\leq h(b)-h(a)
\end{align}

And we're done.

Comment: That's what I was missing! I wasn't plugging -1 and 1 into the function, so my inequality wasn't making any sense. Thank you so much!